# What is the best practice to control visibility for several views at one time

Tags: java, android

It's a basic but important question. I have several views and different app states. On one state, one part of views is visible and the other one is gone. On other state, the other part of views is visible and the first one is gone.

For example:

```
private View line1;
private View line2;
private View line3;
private LinearLayout lineral1; 
private LinearLayout lineral2;

......

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    line1 = findViewById(R.id.line1);
    line2 = findViewById(R.id.line2);
    line3 = findViewById(R.id.line3);
    lineral1 = findViewById(R.id.lineral1)
    lineral2 = findViewById(R.id.lineral2)
}

private void onUIUpdate(int state){
    if(state == 1){
        line1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        line2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        line3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lineral1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lineral2.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }
    else{
        line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        line3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lineral1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lineral2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
    }
}
```

This code looks very lame, can you imagine if you have more views to hide/show. Is there another, better way to control the views visibility depends on apps state?

Comment: You can group the views and assign a parent view for that.Loop through it children.

Comment: Good question, I always wanted something like `findViewsWithTag(Object)` that would return an array of `View`s. Going from JQuery to Android dev was tedious.

Comment: @darnmason yeah tagging the views would be great.